# How can combine a lib.a (a lib C) to support 2 architectures (Intel vs ARM)

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, arm

I’m working on xcode project. How to combine a lib.a to support 2 archs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create universal static library `$ lipo /tmp/x86/lib.a /tmp/arm/lib.a -create -output universal/lib.a`
Hope can help you.